# Is a third-party Canadian criminal record check OK for UK visa applications?

Tags: visas, uk, canada, paperwork, criminal-records

I am about to apply for a Skilled Worker Visa, of UK, and I need to provide some criminal record corresponding to my time in Canada. The official site [here](https://www.rcmp-grc.gc.ca/en/where-do-get-a-criminal-record-check) notes that one may use the services of third-party companies, which are apparently way faster compared to the traditional approach, say, going to local police stations. On the other hand, that webpage also reads as follows:

> Note, however, that not all police services contribute to these
> databanks, and those that do may not share all of their information.

So, will the UK embassy accept such third-party Canadian criminal records for the purpose of applying for UK visas?

Comment: What makes you think that 3rd parties would be faster?

Comment: @NicolasFormichella: Some of them issue the record in less than an hour after online submission.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For visas, as per the [RCMP](https://www.rcmp-grc.gc.ca/en/steps-getting-a-certified-criminal-record-check), you need a certified *(fingerprinted)* record for any type of visa

> Inform the local police agency or accredited fingerprinting company of the reason for the certified criminal record check. It can include:
> [...]
> Foreign travel – Visas, U.S. Waivers, Border Crossing
> [...]

This is further proven by per [UKVI](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/criminal-records-checks-for-overseas-applicants/countries-a-to-f-applying-for-a-criminal-records-check-for-someone-from-overseas#canada) guidances :

> You must provide:

- a full electronic set of fingerprints on form C-216C

Because :

> When name-based criminal record checks do not provide a definite way of confirming a person's identity, you may be asked to provide fingerprints. This is known as a "certified criminal record check."

Third-parties companies *can't* do such checks alone :

> Companies that perform name-based checks

So you must follow the procedure with Police services, which *can* send you getting fingerprinted at an accredited company, but this fingerprinting company is not doing your check themselves

For the processing time, it is [stated](https://www.rcmp-grc.gc.ca/en/processing-times-and-fees) an **approximate** (enphasis mine):

> there is NO match to a criminal record
> **3 business days or less**
> The results are mailed to the address provided and extra time should be allowed for delivery by Canada Post.

> If manual processing is involved and/or if there is a possible match to a criminal record
> **120 business days**
> In some cases more time may be required due to the submission of incomplete information or in an effort to clarify parts of the application with local police. This process ensures the information that is released by CCRTIS is complete and accurate.